# how to change DataGrid DataGridRow DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need to save changes inside my DataGrid. In fact, after modifying cell value by the user the old value replaced by the newest one but when i clicked on that cell i got the old value. Thus i think to save Row DataContext after changes.
Please be informed that i insert a DataTable inside my DataGrid, that's why i need tho update DataContext from code behind.

```
        SelectedMaterial = materialName;
        var cellInfo = DataGridScenarios.CurrentCell;
        DataGridCell gridCell = TryToFindGridCell(DataGridScenarios, cellInfo);
        if (gridCell != null)
            gridCell.Content = SelectedMaterial;
        DataGridRow row = GetSelectedRow(DataGridScenarios);
        row.DataContext = ???????
```

Please any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the DataContext all the butty of the Binding infrastructure is not changing values "By hand".

The reason you still have your old value is because DataGrid's default Binding behavior is that "**UpdateSourceTrigger**" is set to loose focus you need to change it to "**PropertyChanged**" in your column / cell definition(XAML)

Comment: But i didn't have column definition in my XAML cause i put my DataGrid item source as dataTable.

Comment: Add your DataGrid xaml , maybe i'll have an idea .